# casting a byte array stored in a string to a byte array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, arrays

I am being passed a byte array representing a pdf as part of an xml node.

the byte array int the xml looks like this

```
<Document>
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...........</Document>
```

So I first copy the bytearray into a string variable .

```
 string pdfbyte = GetNodeUsingXpath(xpath.....);
```

Now I would like to cast this pdfbyte into a byte array.

```
 byte[] output = (byte[])pdfbyte;
 byte[]  output = byte.parse(pdfbyte);
```

These dont work.

I have looked online but could not find a simple solution to cast a byte array stored in a string variable to a byte array.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Basically, I would like to copy the bytearray that is being sent as part of the xml into a 
byte array variable.

Comment: How are the bytes delimited in the string?

Comment: "So I first copy the bytearray into a string variable" - that sounds like a bad start. What does `GetNodeUsingXpath` actually return here? Is the data base64-encoded, by any chance?

Comment: Yes I think so .. I just updated the xml node for the pdf that I see in the xml structure

Answer (score 4):

If you've got binary data within an XML document, I would *hope* that it's [base64-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Text data and binary data are different, and you shouldn't be trying to store arbitrary binary data in a string directly.

If it is, you can just use:

```
string base64 = GetNodeUsingXpath(xpath.....); 
byte[] output = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

You may find you need to trim the string first:

```
byte[] output = Convert.FromBase64String(base64.Trim());
```

If it's *not* base64, you'll need to look carefully at what the text looks like. It may be hex instead, although that's not terribly likely. If someone has just use `Encoding.GetString(bytes)` to start with, then that code will need to be fixed, and it's almost guaranteed to lose data.

EDIT: Now that we can see some of the data, it does indeed look like it's base64.